# One checkbox selects another JS

Tags: javascript

I have a list with checkboxes, and i need so when one is selected -> it selects one specific checkbox.
The code i got only works once.

```
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.filter__check'); //All the checkboxes
let available = document.querySelector('[name="filter.v.availability"]'); // One that i need be checked

for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    checkbox[i].onclick = function(){
        if(checkbox[i].name != "filter.v.availability" && available.checked == false) {
            available.checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can't understand why it only applies on first click.

[image]

Comment: "The code i got only works once." That means what?

Comment: Can you reproduce the desired output? The check you have **&& available.checked == false** and the **available.checked = true** seems very suspicious.

Comment: @Miraziz added image of how it should work.

Comment: You wrote (in code):  When you click any filter_check checkbox that does not have the name filter.v.availability, it will check the first checkbox that does not have the name filter.v.availability.  Is this not what you intended?  What were you expecting to have happen?

Comment: What do you mean by works once? The code above seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @Wyck Every time i click on any filter_check i need the 'available' became also checked. And the for loop is doing it but only on first click.

Comment: @skara9 yes it does, but it executes only once and i can't understand why.

Comment: @PaleManRiga did you want it to deselect the checkbox when all of them are off?

Comment: Well, it does once probably because it's checked, and second time you go there **available.checked == false** is -> true. Do you uncheck it?

Comment: @Miraziz Yes i uncheck it.

Comment: @PaleManRiga so you want it to toggle on the `available` box when any other checkbox is toggled either on or off?

Comment: Please include your `HTML` template, maybe your issue is related to having wrong names or classes declared to your checkboxes.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized your logic is completely wrong, so I'll end up changing everything completely... please do the following to solve your issue: (1) use `forEach` instead of a `for` loop, (2) according to your code, add an extra iteration inside your `onclick` function to reset your availability check (3) do not store `document.querySelectorAll('.filter__check')` in a variable, call it directly

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `change` event would fit better here.

Also make sure you check if the clicked box is checked so that it wont run when a box is deselected.

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('.filter__check'); //All the checkboxes
let available = document.querySelector('[name="filter.v.availability"]'); // One that i need be checked

for (let i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
    checkbox[i].onchange = function() {
        if(checkbox[i].name !== "filter.v.availability" && checkbox[i].checked) {
            available.checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="filter__check"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="filter__check"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="filter__check"></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" class="filter__check"></li>
</ol>
<input type="checkbox" class="filter__check" name="filter.v.availability">
```